# Changing the color of an icon from FontAwesome?

Tags: html, css, bigcommerce

I am using BigCommerce, and have this for my code:

```css
.icon-cart {
    color: #4ca3c0 !important;
}

.icon-cart a{
    color: #4ca3c0 !important;
}
```

and it won't change the color of the icon. Any help?

http://glymed-plus.mybigcommerce.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fontAwesome installation is messed up.

The reason `color` CSS attribute won't change the color of the shopping cart is because the shopping cart is being rendered by a sprite:

```
.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 14px;
    background: url("http://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/r-13587bfb690318eb6b3c052034841f2aff994eb4/themes/ClassicNext/images/icon_sprite.png") no-repeat 0 -27px;
}
```

(the `background` is loading an image, instead of the icon).

See http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/

You might not have copied the other folders in the installation.

If you remove the `background`, install the other dirs, and keep your HTML, it should work.

---

EDIT: You were right, fontAwesome is correctly installed.

Now change the `<i>` element:

```
<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" title="View Cart">&nbsp;</i>
```

You can set the size and position to better the display, but the `fa` and `fa-shopping-cart` classes must be set for showing the shopping cart icon.

Comment: HEY! I didn't realize it was still pulling the image over (BigCommerce is a bugger to work with.) But now the icon isn't showing at all.

Comment: The icon isn't showing because your installation of fontAwesome is probably broken. See the link in the answer. You have to copy the fonts directory.

Comment: It's showing a fontAwesome icon right below the cart in the search box.

Answer (score 1):

Your icon is not css made, it is a png image that is loaded as the icon's background.

you cannot just 'change' its color, you need to adjust it using [CSS Filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

in your case, you can apply invert on the `<i>` element:

```
-webkit-filter: invert(100%);
```

to change it from gray to white.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 14px;
  background: url("http://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/r-13587bfb690318eb6b3c052034841f2aff994eb4/themes/ClassicNext/images/icon_sprite.png") no-repeat 0 -27px;
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
}
.icon:hover {
  -webkit-filter: invert(0%);
}
```

```html
<i class="icon icon-cart" title="View Cart" style="
    color: red;
">&nbsp;</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

First Remove `!important`

```css
.icon-cart {
    color: #4ca3c0;
}

.icon-cart a{
    color: #4ca3c0;
}
```

now here is how you markup looks like

```
<a href="" title="View Cart">
    <i class="icon icon-cart" title="View Cart">&nbsp;</i>
    <span></span>
</a>
```

`.icon-cart` is `i` and has no child.

So this is not valid:

```css
.icon-cart a{
    color: #4ca3c0;
}
```